# How to transform a data.table into a list of columns that change per ID

Tags: r, data.table, transformation

I was wondering whether someone could help me with the following. I am unsure how to do this in data.table, but I believe that is possible.

Suppose we have the following data.table:

```
test <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3), A = rep(1,11), B = c(1,2,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), C = c(1,2,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,1))
```

We can clearly see that given the ID = 1, the column B and C changes, given ID = 2, the column C only changes and given ID = 3, none of the column changes.
I am unsure how to do this without writing a for loop, which is not feasible given the data size. The output should be:

```
ID | ChangedColumn
1  | B
1  | C
2  | C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert to long format and then compute the changes:

```
melt(test, id.vars = "ID")[, uniqueN(value) > 1, by = .(ID, variable)][(V1), !"V1"]

   ID variable
1:  1        B
2:  1        C
3:  2        C
```

If you're still using an older data.table version that doesn't support column negation using `!`, you can use this instead:

```
melt(test, id.vars = "ID")[, uniqueN(value) > 1, by = .(ID, variable)][(V1), 
                            .(ID, variable)]
```

Comment: So I ran this: 

test <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3), A = rep(1,11), B = c(1,2,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), C = c(1,2,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,1))
melt(test, id.vars = "ID")[, uniqueN(value) > 1, by = .(ID, variable)][(V1), !"V1"]

but there seems to be an error:
Error in !"V1" : invalid argument type

Comment: @Snowflake, see my updated answer and check your data.table version

Answer (score 0):

or you can get the results like matrix with:

```
test[, as.list(lapply(.SD, uniqueN) != 1L), by = ID]
#    ID     A     B     C
# 1:  1 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 2:  2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 3:  3 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```